# TeamCity .NET CLI (dotnet) Restore not including correct version of deep dependency lib

Tags: .net-core, dependencies, teamcity, restore

```
TeamCity Professional 2019.1.2 (build 66342)
Windows 10
.NET Core 2.2.0
```

.NET (CLI) Restore build-step on Visual Studio Solution ( .sln )

One of the Visual Studio Projects ( .csproj ) has this dependency chain :

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.4.0.1` > `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.4.0.1` > `Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2`

But the only artifact created in the `publish` folder is : `

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll v9.0.1
Json.NET .NET Standard 1.0
9.0.1.19813
Json.NET
9.0.1
```

In my local dev environment, if I run `dotnet restore MySolution.sln` from the solution folder , I see the expected packages are pulled-down to the user cache :

`C:\Users\myuser\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2`

By visual inspection I've searched my solution's dependency tree and I don't find any reference to a `.NET Standard` version.  Is there a tool available to make this a more rigorous search ?

Why would the `TeamCity Build Agent` find the `.NET Standard` version as a dependency but not the the `netcoreapp2.2' version ?

Comment: Do you get different results when you run `dotnet restore` command for the solution file from the command line? TeamCity seems to simply call `dotnet` command here...

Comment: dotnet restore MySolution.sln pulls-down package to `Users\MyUser\.nuget\newtonsoft.json.11.0.2` folder. Strangely it's only on `TeamCity Build Agent` the wrong version is pulled.

Comment: Perhaps the TeamCity agent does the same but to another cache directory. You can find the nuget cache in the directory `%windir%\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache` or `%windir%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache` in the case when a TeamCity agent is running like a windows service under LocalSystem account. Try changing this account for TeamCity agent service and you will find appropriate packages in related cache.

Comment: TeamCity agent just runs the command line `dotnet ...` there, so there is no any magic

Comment: May be this topic "dependency assets": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets could be useful